# Alert message after completing the installation of any software

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, virtual-machine, alert

i have 3 virtual machines and i have started installing XYZ software on each machine and i continue with my work on my main machine. I need to intermediately check the VMs for installation status of software. Sometimes the installation is completed long back and i go and check it very late. Which results into delay in starting my work on that Vm on which installation is completed.

Is it possible to get any alert or Notification from the Vms on main machine about completion of installation of the software.
Can we create automation script in Selenium where we can input Vms name or no on which installation is running.